# Adding glow to an object made by Raphael when an input form is clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events, raphael

I have created a shape using the raphael JS library. I have an input field on my page. I want to toggle a glow around that shape when the input field is clicked on.
Here is the code I've already tried:

```
var searchBoxHtml =  document.getElementsByName("searchBox");
searchBoxHtml.onclick= function () {europe_africa.glow({width: 10,fill: false, opacity: 0.5, offsetx: 0,offsety: 0,color:'white'}); };
```

This is not working. I have also tried putting the event handler inside the input tag and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out my mistake. I just had to add a [0] at the end of `getElementsByName("searchBox")` as the value it returns is an array.

Comment: You should accept this as the answer so it can help others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a `z-index: 9999`, as well as a `position: relative` to your searchBox element? It seems that the raphael object might be sitting on top of your div element.